# Visual studio 2013 show "no android sdk found", with xamrin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-sdk-2.3

I installed successfully the vs installer for visual studio 2013. it worked fine yesterday. but today it shows following error

[image]

there were android sdk. how can I install it now to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Click the `Change`. It will show a popup. Specify your android SDK folder path there.

---

Usually android SDK will be in your : `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk`.

Check for it.

---